# Default to Windows Authentication for SSMS login

Tags: login, ssms

After launching SQL Server Management Studio 2012, the "Connect to Server" prompt is displayed. In the "Authentication" dropdown, it defaults to "SQL Server Authentication", which I have used in the past, however I'd like it to default to "Windows Authentication" now.

I've looked through every setting I can find in SSMS, but it doesn't seem to be configurable. I've also logged in using "Windows Authentication", however it doesn't remember this the next time I launch SSMS.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: I'd probably start by renaming `user\AppData\Roaming\SQL Server Management Studio` to another name, and launching the program.,

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for the suggestion. I found it at `user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio`, and renaming did cause a new folder with the original name to be created... though the situation remains unchanged.

Comment: then the information is likely in the registry, as it is a per-user configuration.

Comment: just out of curiosity, are you running SMSS as Admin? My recollection is that the Connection dialog should remember your last login, so if its losing that info, I wonder if running as admin might allow you to login once as a windows user, close the program, and then launch it again as a non-elevated user to see if it stuck.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas. The administrator workaround didn't do the trick.  I also tried running as admin twice in a row to see if it stuck. Any idea where in the registry to look to delete the login information?